# DSL-like OnClick-listener for a custom view using kotlin in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view

I'm trying to create an DSL-like OnClick-listener (in kotlin) for a custom view that I'm using several places in the Android project I'm currently working on. The view has an ImageView, a primary textview and a secondary textview. I'm trying to create a listener-helper that allows you to only override specific methods of an interface instead of all of them (inspired by [this article](https://antonioleiva.com/listeners-several-functions-kotlin/?utm_source=twitter.com&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=listeners-with-several-functions-in-kotl&utm_content=14003943)). But I can't get it working. Actually it doesn't even work using regular OnClick listeners.

Here's my ErrorMessageView:

```
class ErrorMessageView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = 0,
    defStyleRes: Int = 0
    ) : FrameLayout(context, attrs, defStyle, defStyleRes) {

    private var mOnClickListener: OnErrorMessageViewClickListener? = null

    init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
            R.layout.custom_errorview,
            this,
            true)
        ButterKnife.bind(this)
    }

    interface OnErrorMessageViewClickListener {
        fun onImageClick()
        fun onPrimaryTextClick()
        fun onSecondaryTextClick()
    }

    ... left out for brevity ...

    fun setOnErrorMessageViewClickListener(
        onViewClickListener: OnErrorMessageViewClickListener?) {
        this.mOnClickListener = onViewClickListener
    }


    fun setOnErrorMessageViewClickListener(init: ErrorMessageViewClickListenerHelper.() -> Unit) {
        val listener = ErrorMessageViewClickListenerHelper()
        listener.init()
    mOnClickListener = listener
}

    @OnClick(R.id.image_container)
    internal fun onImageViewClick() {
        Timber.d("Clicked image view")
        mOnClickListener?.onImageClick()
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.primary_text_container)
    internal fun onPrimaryTextViewClick() {
        Timber.d("Clicked primary textview")
        mOnClickListener?.onPrimaryTextClick()
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.secondary_text_container)
    internal fun onSecondaryTextViewClick() {
        Timber.d("Clicked secondary textview")
        mOnClickListener?.onSecondaryTextClick()
    }

}
```

And here's my helper class:

```
private typealias ErrorViewClickListener = () -> Unit

open class ErrorMessageViewClickListenerHelper : ErrorMessageView.OnErrorMessageViewClickListener {

    private var mImageClick: ErrorViewClickListener? = null

    fun onImageClick(onImageClick: ErrorViewClickListener?) {
        mImageClick = onImageClick
    }

    override fun onImageClick() {
        mImageClick?..invoke()
    }

    private var mPrimaryTextClick: ErrorViewClickListener? = null

    fun onPrimaryTextClick(onPrimaryTextClick: ErrorViewClickListener?) {
        mPrimaryTextClick = onPrimaryTextClick
    }

    override fun onPrimaryTextClick() {
        mPrimaryTextClick?.invoke()
    }

    private var mSecondaryTextClick: ErrorViewClickListener? = null

    fun onSecondaryTextClick(onSecondaryTextClick: ErrorViewClickListener?) {
        mSecondaryTextClick = onSecondaryTextClick
    }

    override fun onSecondaryTextClick() {
        mSecondaryTextClick?.invoke()
    }
}
```

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_container"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dialog_worklist_image_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dialog_worklist_image_size"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/primary_text_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/image_container"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/image_container"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/image_container" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondary_text_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/primary_text_container" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm using the helper in my code like this, but nothing gets logged (It's almost as if no clicklistener can be attached):

```
override fun setWorklistNotEnabledMessage(showMessage: Boolean) {
    if (showMessage) {
        mView?.dialog_worklist_recyclerview?.visibility = View.GONE
        mView?.dialog_worklist_errorview?.apply {
            visibility = View.VISIBLE
            setSecondaryTextClickListener(View.OnClickListener { Timber.d("Test secondary click") })
            setErrorDrawable(R.drawable.ic_worklist_disabled_black_24dp)
            setPrimaryText(R.string.global_worklist_disabled_error)
            setSecondaryText(R.string.dialog_worklist_worklist_disabled_error_secondary_text)
            setOnErrorMessageViewClickListener {
                onSecondaryTextClick { Timber.d("Test secondary click") }
                onPrimaryTextClick { Timber.d("Test primary click") }
                onImageClick { Timber.d("Test image click") }
                // . this@WorklistDialog
            }
        }

    } else {
        mView?.dialog_worklist_errorview?.apply {
            visibility = View.GONE
            setErrorDrawable(null)
            setPrimaryText("")
            setSecondaryText("")
            setOnErrorMessageViewClickListener(null)
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion to what is wrong with my code?

Btw. the above code is used in a DialogFragment - that is why you might notice the mView?. as a bit awkward. But that is the way to get a handle on the views in a dialog.

Comment: The setup of the helper looks good, are you calling the methods on the `mOnClickListener` property somewhere in the class?

Comment: Thanks for the input on the helper. For the mOnclickListener I'm using butterknife to handle the onClick events and triggering the mOnClickListener method, but nothing gets triggered. I've edited the question to show the actual code.

Comment: Butterknife obviously doesn't work as expected when used with kotlin. Will probably have to find some other way to create a binding to a OnClickListener.

Comment: Are you using `kapt` in your `build.gradle` file for annotation processing?

Comment: Yes I'm using kapt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was just about to start crying when I finally found the solution - OMG.

The problem was the SwipeRefreshLayout in the layout file for the dialogfragment, which can be seen here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/dialog_worklist_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <com.conhea.smartgfr.ui.examination.layouts.ErrorMessageView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_worklist_errorview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dialog_worklist_toolbar" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/dialog_worklist_progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dialog_worklist_toolbar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_worklist_swiperefreshlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/dialog_worklist_toolbar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_worklist_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The SwipeRefreshLayout was blocking the custom ErrorMessageView from being clickable.

After adding `mView?.dialog_worklist_swiperefreshlayout?.isEnabled = false` to the below in my DialogFragment everything started working:

```
override fun setWorklistNotEnabledMessage(showMessage: Boolean) {
    if (showMessage) {
        mView?.dialog_worklist_recyclerview?.visibility = View.GONE
        mView?.dialog_worklist_swiperefreshlayout?.isEnabled = false
        mView?.dialog_worklist_errorview?.apply {
            visibility = View.VISIBLE
            setErrorDrawable(R.drawable.ic_worklist_disabled_black_24dp)
            setPrimaryText(R.string.global_worklist_disabled_error)
            setSecondaryText(R.string.dialog_worklist_worklist_disabled_error_secondary_text)
            setOnErrorMessageViewClickListener {
                onSecondaryTextClick { Timber.d("Test secondary click") }
                onPrimaryTextClick { Timber.d("Test primary click") }
                onImageClick { Timber.d("Test image click") }
            }
        }

    } else {
        mView?.dialog_worklist_errorview?.apply {
            visibility = View.GONE
            setErrorDrawable(null)
            setPrimaryText("")
            setSecondaryText("")
            setOnErrorMessageViewClickListener(null)
        }
    }
}
```